# why nodejs file system read console first then read the file

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, filesystems, fs

I can read the files using nodejs file system:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./assets/test1.txt', (err, data) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data.toString())
})

console.log('hello shawn!')
```

Why `console.log('hello shawn!')` read first times then read the `console.log(data.toString())`?

Is there any other things in file system read `data` first then read below `console`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `.readFile` is a asynchronous operation. Its last parameter is callback function, which is started after operation is done. I recommend read something about [callbacks](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) and [event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

You can use a synchronous version of function `readFileSync` or use `utils.promisify` to convert callback function to promise and use async/await then [example](https://stackabuse.com/converting-callbacks-to-promises-in-node-js/).